# How to setup default value of fetched data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am fetching data from my "backend" CMS - everything works fine, but when I want to setup default value I am getting error of undefined data.

**My content is divided into some categories e.g.**

```
   const [category1, setCategory1] = useState([]);
   const [category2, setCategory2] = useState([]);
```

**Then I am fetching data from backend**

```
  useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            const result = await client.query(
                Prismic.Predicates.at('document.type', 'post'),
                { pageSize: 100 }
            );
            if (result) {
                const category1Arr = [];
                const category2Arr = [];
                result.results.forEach((post) => {
                    switch (post.data.category[0].text) {
                        case 'Category1':
                            category1Arr.push(post);
                            break;
                        case 'Category2':
                           category2Arr.push(post);
                            break;
                        default:
                            console.warn('Missing blog post category.');
                    }
                });
                setCategory1(category1Arr);
                setCategory2(category2Arr);
                return setDocData(result);
            } else {
                console.warn(
                    'Not found'
                );
            }
    };
    fetchData();
}, []);
```

Code above works **without any issues**, BUT chosen category should have one post opened by default.

I am having menu when you can pick category and therefore I am using `activeComponent` function.

```
const [activeComponent, setActiveComponent] = useState('category1');
const modifyActiveComponent = React.useCallback(
        (newActiveComponent) => {
            setActiveComponent(newActiveComponent);
        },
        [setActiveComponent]
);
```

So category1 is active on default, therefore the category should also have default post.

**This is what I tried:**

```
  const [postTitle, setPostTitle] = useState('');
  const [postText, setPostText] = useState([]);

{activeComponent === 'category1' &&
category1.length > 0 && category1.map((post) => {
return ( <button onClick={()=> {setPostTitle(post.data.title[0].text); setPostText(post.data.body)}}
```

And data are shown typical just as a `{postTitle}` & `{postText}`

I tried to put default value in each category like this

```
useEffect(() => {
        if (activeComponent === 'category1') {
            setPostTitle(category1[2].data.title[0].text);
            setPostText(category1[2].data.body);
        }
        if (activeComponent === 'category2') {
            // same here just with category2        }
}, [activeComponent, category1, category2]);
```

But the code above gives me an error or undefined data even though it should be correct.

How can I achieve to make a default value with this logic above? Everything works like charm, just the default data does not work :(

This is array of objects:

[image]

Comment: what is the error that you get?

Comment: So if I do `setPostTitle(category1[2].data.title[0].text)` its giving me TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined, even though path to the title is correct.

Comment: it can be possible that in the first render, the `data` is unpopulated and in the 2nd or third render, where you have managed to fill up the data in the above logic, the value is filled up. Can you check if that's the case using `console.log` and the debugger?

Comment: if I `console.log` just category1 it prints me out array of my posts, but when I try to console.log deeper path, it does not work. Funny thing is it works with `category1[2].id`- it prints corrent id, but with .data it does not work.

Comment: Does your `console.log` print the `data` object?

Comment: I updated my post wit array of objects and its objects if I console.log category1

Comment: is this `console.log` right in the same `if` statement as `setPostTitle` and `setPostText`?

Comment: Both works the same - outside also inside the if statement.

Comment: @TechGirl can you add just one `console.log` ( remove others and cleanup the output console so that it isn't polluted with junk ) in the first statement of the `useEffect`, if it prints out results multiple times... it's the first result that you need to be concerned about, can you check that it's not `undefined`?

Comment: So @SamridhTuladhar I just checked and I `console.log(category1[2].data.title[0].text)`, which came out correctly - then I applied it on frontend and worked also, but once I reloaded page the error came again - very strange and frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

In your last piece of code you have a typo, here:

```
useEffect(() => {
        if (activeComponent === 'category1') {
            setPostTitle(category1[2].data.title[0].text);
            setPostText(category[2].data.body);
        }
        if (activeComponent === 'category2') {
            // same here just with category2        }
    }, [activeComponent, category1, category2]);
```

it should be:

```
useEffect(() => {
        if (activeComponent === 'category1') {
            setPostTitle(category1[2].data.title[0].text);
            setPostText(category1[2].data.body);
        }
        if (activeComponent === 'category2') {
            // same here just with category2        }
    }, [activeComponent, category1, category2]);
```

in the first `if` statement, in second `setPostText`, you have `category` instead of `category1`.

Comment: OP has commented that they have a problem with `setPostTitle` too

Comment: Thanks @Arpit, but that's not the issue it is just typo here, in my code is correct with real category names.

Comment: hmm... If that is the case, then there must be some logic error where you are trying to access the `data` object too soon, you should do some debugging as suggested by @SamridhTuladhar